# SpecRun.SpecFlow 1.2.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0

Tags: .net, testing, nuget, win-universal-app, specflow

We have written a Universal Windows application and want to use SpecFlow for testing. We created a Universal Windows test project. Trying to install the SpecRun.SpecFlow NuGet package fails with this error:

```
    ...
Installing SpecRun.Runner 1.2.0.
Installing SpecFlow 1.9.0.
Installing SpecRun.SpecFlow 1.2.0.
SpecRun.SpecFlow 1.2.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.
SpecFlow 1.9.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.
SpecRun.SpecFlow 1.2.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm).
SpecFlow 1.9.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm).
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm).
SpecRun.SpecFlow 1.2.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm-aot).
SpecFlow 1.9.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm-aot).
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm-aot).
    etc.
```

How to solve this? Are specific project settings required? Or can someone certainly confirm SpecFlow is indeed incompatible? The [SpecFlow documentation](http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Setup-SpecFlow-Projects/) is fairly unspecific about supported platforms.

Installed package:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SpecFlow and SpecRun.SpecFlow does not support UAPs directly.

As workaround, you can do following:

- Create a Portable Class Library (PCL) and set the targets to .Net 4.5.1 and Windows Universal 10.0
- Extract the code you want to test and put it into the PCL
  But be carefull, you do not have the full .NET Apis
  available. Only the subset of the targets you selected for the PCL.
- Add a reference to the PCL in your UAP
- Create a Unit Test Project and add a reference to the PCL
- Add SpecRun.SpecFlow to the Unit Test Project

Now you can use SpecFlow and SpecRun.SpecFlow in the Unit Test Project.

Answer (score 2):

The SpecRun.SpecFlow 1.2.0 NuGet package only contains assemblies for .NET 3.5 so you cannot install it into a Universal App (UAP) project.

Comment: Thank you Matt! This package is recommended for any .NET test project hence if this packages is restricted to 3.5, what is the correct approach to get SpecFlow installed for non-3.5 projects?

Comment: I've used SpecFlow with .NET 4.5. I think Matt is just saying that you can't use it with a "Universall App Project" specifically.